# Skip instead of terminate program when array out of bounds (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Is there a way to skip the current command when the array is out of bounds?

```
memory[count] = allProcesses[processIndex[index]+temp];
```

The array will go out of bounds when it tries to access a variable that doesn't exist. I just want to print out an error message and keep going, but every time it happens, the program terminates

What i've tried:

```
try {
    memory[count] = allProcesses[processIndex[index]+temp];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Page Fault");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
```

Here is the error message:

```
...
Adding Process 10, address 48214, page 1868, offset 12, value 550 to memory location 54
Adding Process 11, address 30649, page 557, offset 13, value 229 to memory location 55
Adding Process 11, address 46819, page 343, offset 7, value 519 to memory location 56
Adding Process 11, address 54762, page 94, offset 14, value 425 to memory location 57
Page Fault
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 726384
    at MMU.MMUProcess(MMU.java:58)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:73)
```

Comment: When it terminates does it show your "Page Fault" message?  Can you post a stacktrace if you have one?

Comment: The errormessage would help greatly, other than that. i would say that you should sanitize your data before it's actually used as an index.

Comment: It would also help if you posted a larger code sample and explained how it differed from the desired behavior.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the code? you're already catching exceptions, so if you give us a bit more of the context maybe we would be able to understand what your actual problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure the program will not terminate if there is an excpetion in the following code as you are catching the Exception:

```
try {
    memory[count] = allProcesses[processIndex[index]+temp];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Page Fault");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
```

What I believe is there is some other code above or below this code, which is not encapsulated under try/catch and throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's terminating for another reason. For example, this code:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        try {
            array[3] = 4;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("I didn't die");
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
I didn't die
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an uncaught exception at mmu.java:58 that caused the termination, try catching that line and print a stack trace, that should help solving the problem.